# CRM 2011 Developer Toolkit Cannot Add Entity Id as Image Parameter from CRM Explorer

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've got a problem with my CRM Explorer from dev toolkit. I installed this from SDK.

Why can't I choose entity id as parameters when I want to set up my plug-in step image?

I have to *remember* to manually add it in RegisterFile.crmregister and it would be overwrited once I add other fields from the CRM Explorer.

I can of course choose the entity id from Plugin Registration Tool after the plug-ins solution being deployed using the Developer Toolkit.

Does anyone experience the same as me?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it from the context.

In the case of a toolkit-powered plugin, it's accessible in the `xxxExecute()` method through `localContext.PluginExecutionContext.PrimaryEntityId`

Beware that it doesn't simply exist in a Pre-Create (the record doesn't exist yet!)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I know how to do it in the code. When you want to create a plugin with the Dev Toolkit, you can choose what parameters that would be included in for example in the Account Post Update image. You can then choose many different parameters, but not accountid.

Comment: Here is the screen shot [link](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=8981FF8848F5239E&id=8981FF8848F5239E%21382)